# Naming Convention for populating properties using a function

Tags: c#, properties, naming-conventions

I am trying to separate/refactor code into folders and move all my 'Fill' properties into a logical place.

Is there a technical name for populating properties using a function

example:

```
public class AccountsView
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

This would be place in its own Class .. right now its within the above class

```
public static AccountsView FillCustomerView(Account data)
{
    view.Email = data.Email;
    view.FirstName = data.FirstName;
    view.LastName = data.LastName;
    return view;
}
```

What would this 'FillCustomerView()' function be called?

Comment: This is actually object mapping. There are tools which do that (e.g. Automapper)

Comment: Well if your code would work, I would call it a mapper method.

Comment: Don't do this, you are creating dependency from AccountsView to Account

Comment: You could use an `implicit` or `explicit` conversion operator? Not sure if this would just hide the logic more though. It really depends on what your trying to achieve here.

Comment: I would call it `Assign()`, but it kind of depends what class the method is in... Static helper class? Member of AccountsView? Member of Account? Can't tell from the sample.

Comment: @DavidKEgghead: Use AutoMapper, or you manually map by yourself by creating Mapper class rather than using static method

Comment: @CuongLe +1. many people fail to notice the importance of decoupling DTOs/projections from domain entities.

Comment: @ZdeslavVojkovic Would "Projection" objects be more specific than 'Mapping' objects ?

Comment: I am not sure. DTOs have specific meaning as a pattern. Projection is more general term for this. Mapping, at least for me, refers to object/type which defines the logic for conversion between DTO and entity, not the instances themselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The concept described here is called object mapping, and in this example it is implemented as a method on view model.

The drawback of this implementation is that it couples the view models to domain models, and this is usually frowned upon. To avoid this, mapper objects are typically used - they define projection from one model to another.

You could use some already existing implementation. Most popular seems to be [Automapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/), but there are others. E.g. the excellent [ServiceStack](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Auto-mapping) framework also supports it.

Comment: Yep and ServiceStack briefly explains its support in its [Auto mapping wiki](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Auto-mapping)

Comment: Yes, I have linked to exactly that page :) btw, great work! I am evangelizing it heavily at my enterprise-certified WCF-drinking client - with no success so far, though :(

Comment: ahh apologies, just assumed it was just a link to the website. Yep know the story, extremely hard to break the status-quo, thx for trying tho!

Comment: "no one ever got fired for choosing Microsoft".